# How to show Advanced Custom Fields data above share links, pagination, etc

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin two create two fields, review score and review summary.

I can display these fields on a post no problem, but it displays after everything else like share buttons, author box, pagination, etc.

How can I modify my code so that the custom fields show above everything else, just after the last paragraph of the post?

This is my code to display my custom fields:

```
<?php if( get_field('review_score') ): ?>
                                <div class="review-score">
                                    <h1>The Last Word</h1>
                                    <div class="score-section">
                                    <span class="review-the-score"><?php the_field('review_score'); ?></span><span class="review-out-of">/10</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="summary-section">
                                    <span class="review-summary"><?php the_field('review_summary'); ?></span></div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

Thanks for your help/
```

Answer (score 1):

Plugins typically insert their content via `the_content` filter. The filter runs when `the_content()` function is called, and passes the content through the filter before output.

Remember, with a filter, you need to append to the existing content, then `return` the results.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpd_content_filter', 10 );

function wpd_content_filter( $content ){
    if ( is_single() && get_field( 'review_score' ) )
        $content .= '<span class="review-the-score">' . get_field( 'review_score' ) . '</span>';

    return $content;
}
```

The third argument of `add_filter` is the priority (10 in the above example, the default). You may need to make this a lower number if plugin content is appearing above your own.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this to wrok, I decided to ditch ACF and just work with wordpress custom fields instead, here is my code which now shows the review score and summary above all other plugin stuff, author box etc.

```
    //show review score above other plugin stuff
add_filter( 'the_content', 'gwad_review_score', 1);

function gwad_review_score( $content ){

    global $post;

    $revscore = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_score', true);
    $revsummary = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'review_summary', true);

    if ($revscore) {

        $content = $content . '<div class="review-score">' . $revscore . '<p>' . $revsummary . '</p>' . '</div>';

        return $content;

    }else{

    }

}
```